# Align horizontally H4 tag inside multiple divs

Tags: html, css

i need align/center H4 tag inside multiples divs. I try with text-align: center; but doesn work.

```
<div data-href="http://codigomasivo.com.ar/dev/douglas/transmission/" tabindex="1" data-target="_self" class="linkarea clearfix accent1  background-transparent">
    <div class="first">
        <img src="http://codigomasivo.com.ar/dev/douglas/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/trans_green.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="last"><h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Transmission</span></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Look this image:

[image]

I need to center "transmission" text, is the only text not centered. My web is this http://codigomasivo.com.ar/dev/douglas/home/
Thanks a lot

Comment: We're going to need the CSS that goes along with that HTML...

Comment: @user3763909 answer provided by jaunt is not the right solution, your design will break-up uppon screen resolution changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `padding: 20px;` to `.linkarea .first` instead of `.linkarea` and that should give you your desired effect.

Comment: Applying `padding: 20px` is not the solution, as it depends on the screen resolution. the picture should be aligned to center which is not right now

Answer (score 0):

Not too be a jerk but you have 2 suspension sections and timing section goes to suspension section.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```html
<div class="linkarea clearfix accent1 background-transparent">
    <div class="first" style="text-align: center">
        <img style="display: inline-block" src="http://codigomasivo.com.ar/dev/douglas/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/trans_green.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="last"><h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #232323;">Transmission</span></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```